# Ubuntu One does not work right with Gnome 3 in 11.04

Tags: 11.04, ubuntu-one, gnome

Today, I decided to try Ubuntu One. But unfortunately it's not working:

[image]

Did anyone encounter any similar problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gnome 3 changed several dbus apis in incompatible ways, and the fixes for those changes are not in 11.04. There's a [bug tracking the progess](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-sso-client/+bug/745540) if you're interested.